# I want to download Multiple images as a zip file using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to download multiple image when i click to download button but unfortunately i am getting empty folder in zip file , images or files are not downloading in zip file please help me how can i resolve that ? thanks.

Note :- I am getting images or files in array from db  like this **["zFbf2cGRPLTaXbqzA5VWt8FZTjhXkt4LoC041fIH.jpeg","ucy0WknOKMhuNtfqcRgmWUgpvp2IPKhU84lU2tAq.jpeg"]**

**html view**

```
<a href="javascript:;"   class="download text-primary p-5" data-original-title="Download 
  Files"  title=""   data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" >
          <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
```

**script**

```
      let url="{{Config('yourstitchart.file_url')}}"
      //url = http://localhost/yourstitichart/yourstitichart.com/web/public/uploads/images/
 
      window.onload = function(event) {
        let val= document.querySelector('.download')
            

         let files= {!!$event->image_gallery!!}

       // let files=zFbf2cGRPLTaXbqzA5VWt8FZTjhXkt4LoC041fIH.jpeg,
       ucy0WknOKMhuNtfqcRgmWUgpvp2IPKhU84lU2tAq.jpeg

        var zip = new JSZip();
  
      var folder = zip.folder("files");
  
    files.map(async item=>folder.file(url+item))

    val.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{

      zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})

            .then(function(content) {

            saveAs(content, "example.zip");
      });
    });
      }
    },
  },
```